# Referencing a variable column value in a Google Sheet formula

Tags: excel-formula, syntax, reference, google-sheets-formula, indirection

I want to use the value of a cell as the column value of a cell reference in a formula.

For example:

- cell `A1` has the value `12`
- In another cell, I want to reference the value of another cell using a hard-coded Row with the value of `A1` as the column, like this: `=$F$[value of A1]`
- So the result is `=$F$12` which displays the value in `F12`.

I think using `INDIRECT` is required but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it like this:

```
=INDIRECT("F"&A1)
```

or if you want to lock A1 value:

```
=INDIRECT("F"&$A$1)
```

---

```
=INDIRECT("All Active - Paid Accounts!F"&$A$1)
```

Comment: Definitely worked for same sheet reference but I left out the fact that I was referencing a cell from another sheet, to keep it simple. When I add to end of sheet reference, it get error: `='All Active - Paid Accounts'!INDIRECT("F"&$A$1)`. Same error if I remove the `$`s. Any insight there?

Comment: @CraigConover it needs to be like this: `=INDIRECT("All Active - Paid Accounts!F"&$A$1)`